# How to calculate width and height of a div in 9:16 aspect ratio

Tags: css

How can I create a div with an aspect ration of `9:16`. I have got some examples of `16:9` but when I am trying to calculate the aspect ratio of `9:16` the height of div is getting too long.

How can I calculate the `9:16` aspect ratio where a `div` will fit in any kind of viewport.

Comment: `width:56vh;height:100vh;`  I guess ? Until width is less than 56vh ...

Answer (score 1):

To keep the aspect ratio the same, make sure that you are using the same units for both the width and height. You should also use appropriate units that are based off of the dimensions of the user's viewport. For example, using `vw` units:

```css
.my-9-16-aspect-ratio {
    width: 9vw;
    height: 16vw;

    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-9-16-aspect-ratio"></div>
```

You can then scale these numbers up or down as desired.

You can also use the css `calc()` function along with a css variable to avoid calculating the height by hand like so:

```css
.my-9-16-aspect-ratio {
    --width: 95vw;
    width: var(--width);
    height: calc((16/9) * var(--width));

    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-9-16-aspect-ratio"></div>
```